# Python open a variable as filename using with open

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm stuck on the best way to use a variable stored within a function to read a .csv file.
I've only used the `with` `open` before using a path like `(r"C:/Users\James\Desktop\test_data.csv")`. If I store `(r"C:/Users\James\Desktop\test_data.csv")` into `FilePath = (r"C:/Users\James\Desktop\test_data.csv")` and use `with open(FilePath) as f:` it works. So I'm sure I'm messing something up within my function `def select_input_file():` I have tried `with open(r,(input_file_path)) as f:` `with open(r(input_file_path)) as f:` but cant get it to work. Fyi, using python 3.8.5. I've reduced the code to include what i think is necessary for this question. Cheers

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageTk
import csv
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

def select_input_file():
    global input_file_path
    input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
    with open(input_file_path) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Import", command=select_input_file)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `r` modifier only applies to string literals, because string literals have to support special escape sequences.  You don't need to worry about it if you are getting your file path from somewhere else.

Comment: `askopenfile()` doesn't return a file path as you seem to expect, it returns an *open file*, which you can directly iterate over (and then explicitly `.close()`, since there's no way to use `with` in this case).  Or you can change that to `askopenfilename()`, and leave the rest of your code as is.

Comment: great, thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I believe is that you are using `askopenfile` instead of `askopenfilename` and that would supposedly solve the issue.

What `askopenfile` does is that it opens a file for you to read or write on to, similar to `open()`.

But what `askopenfilename` does is that it returns the path of the file that you select and here it is what you want to use, as your code revolves around the path of the file.

Alternatively you could also write the code in a way that uses just the `askopenfile` and omit the `open()` and `askopenfilename` in your code too.

[Click here for more Information on askopenfilename and example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-askopenfile-function-in-tkinter/)

If any doubts or errors, do let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, this `askopenfilename()` did the trick. However, its only reading the first line of the .csv file? has it got to do with the way the variable is stored / called?

Comment: you are using `DictReader`, why not `reader`. What is your need with the csv

Comment: To read the .csv and input to `tkinter` `treeview` I think I need to use `DictReader` because `reader` will look for `integer numbers`. My column names are indexed so using `reader` gives error `TypeError`

Comment: i dont believe reader would give an error. Are you sure? after using `reader`, you can loop through the results and get all the values

Comment: using `reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter =' ', quotechar='|')` and leaning on this doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html im getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices not str`

Comment: my bad as, you stated I need to run through the values `for line in reader:`

Comment: Did you get the desired output?